# Entry binded value is always 0

Tags: xamarin.forms

I got my numeric `entry` binded to viewmodel's `SelectedAmount`. Nevertheless `value` is always `0`, even if i put some value on gui in `entry` it goes to `property` and i see `_selectedAmount` as 0.
What could be wrong?

**Xaml:**

```
<Entry Placeholder="Amount" Text="{Binding SelectedAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric" MaxLength="5" />
```

**ViewModel binded property:**

```
private int _selectedAmount;
public int SelectedAmount
{
    get => _selectedAmount;
    set
    {
        if (_selectedAmount <= 0)
           _pageService.DisplayAlert("Warning", "Value has to be between 1 - 10000", "ok", "cancel");
        else
            SetValue(ref _selectedAmount, value);
        }
}
```

Comment: `if (_selectedAmount <= 0)`, did you mean `if (value <= 0)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line

```
        if (_selectedAmount <= 0)
```

Whenever you try to enter an number in your entry the setter of `SelectedAmount` will be called & it will always check for your condition `if (_selectedAmount <= 0)` & as `_selectedAmount` hasn't been change throughout the session it will always stays as 0 & return 0, cuz your compiler will never enter the else part & it will never set the input value to `_selectedAmount`

You have to change your condition as

```
if (value < 1 || value > 10000)
```

I guess that's what you was looking for.

Let me know if your issue was something else than this.